# Multiple Where Clause in Laravel not working as needed

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to get all the expired listings from the db. the table has three fields for the expiry date, to_date_1, to_date_2, to_date_3.
date 2&3 may have a null value but date 1 always has a value. If date 3 is not null I want the query to compare with date 3 and skip date1 &2. if date 3 is null, the query should compare with date 2, otherwise date 1 will be the expiry date. here is my query.

```php
$query = Listing::query()
    ->where('vendor_id', $vendor->id)
    ->where('is_deleted', 0)->where('is_published', 1)->where('is_approved', 1)
    ->where(function ($q) {
        return $q->WhereNotNull('to_date_3')->Where('to_date_3', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
    })
    ->where(function ($q) {
        return $q->WhereNotNull('to_date_2')->Where('to_date_2', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
    })
    ->where(function ($q) {
        return $q->orWhere('to_date_1', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    $listings = $query->paginate(10);
```

Here is a sample data:

| id | from_date_1 | to_date_1 | from_date_2 | to_date_2 | from_date_3 | to_date_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-10 | 2021-08-15 | 2021-08-16 | 2021-08-31 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-15 |
| 2 | 2021-06-25 | 2021-08-10 | 2021-08-11 | 2021-08-22 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 2021-06-25 | 2021-08-20 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

if today date is: 21-08-2021, the result should be record: 1 & 2

Comment: can you check `->where(function ($q) { return $q->WhereNotNull('to_date_3')->Where('to_date_3', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')); })`  what return?

Comment: I manage to get the full query as sql, logically it is not correct that's why it returns null.. I update my post

Comment: try `->toSql()` to check your query as sql

Comment: @PavloMezhevikin, yea the query is in the post already, somehow it is working but the result is not 100% correct yet.

Comment: Is that SQL is what you want? Or is that the bad SQL you get from the Laravel code?

Comment: @miken32 it is the original sql, no it is not what i want as the result is not the expired listings based on the dates specified

Answer (score 0):

Try use **orWhere**

```
->where('is_deleted', 0)->where('is_published', 1)->where('is_approved', 1)
        ->where(function ($q) {
            return $q->WhereNotNull('to_date_3')->Where('to_date_3', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($q) {
            return $q->WhereNotNull('to_date_2')->Where('to_date_2', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($q) {
            return $q->orWhere('to_date_1', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
        })
```

More about [parameters grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping)

**UPDATING** (where -> orWhere -> orWhere give you your sql)

Comment: I have tried, it is returning wrong result.. thanks

Comment: thank you for the help, but this query is not working as needed. If to_date_3 is not null it should be the expired date, otherwise it is to_date_2, if to_date_2 is null, then the expiry date should be to_date_1.. this is my question from the beginning, hope you can help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Pavlo said group your query inside a where

```
 $query = Listing::query()
        ->where(function ($query) { // Wrap you code inside a where
            $query->where('vendor_id', $vendor->id)
                ->where('is_deleted', 0)->where('is_published', 1)->where('is_approved', 1)
                ->where(function ($q) {
                    return $q->WhereNotNull('to_date_3')->Where('to_date_3', '<', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
                })
                ->where(function ($q) {
                    return $q->WhereNotNull('to_date_2')->Where('to_date_2', '<', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
                })
                ->where(function ($q) {
                    return $q->orWhere('to_date_1', '<', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
                });
        })
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    $listings = $query->paginate(10);
```

Comment: tried, I will get $vendor is undefined. I have tried the following but the result is empty.
$query = Listing::query()
            ->where('vendor_id', $vendor->id)
            ->otherwhere()
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

Comment: remove ```query()``` and give it a try

Comment: @OsamaShaki in this case `function ($query) use ($vendor)` must help

Comment: this should be ```WhereNotNull``` ```whereNotNull``` right ? others also

Comment: I tried function ($query) use ($vendor).. thanks but the query return nothing.. I have 2 expired listings with past dates but the query is not retuning

Comment: I removed query() but same..no result